# Angular 7 - issue displaying data with *ngFor (data not showing)

Tags: angular, ngfor

i have the below Json example that im trying to bind it in *ngFor:

```
[
    {
        "employeeId": 1,
        "name": "johnny",
        "dob": "4/20/1992 12:00:00 AM",
        "salary": "100"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 2,
        "name": "test",
        "dob": "10/10/2000 12:00:00 AM",
        "salary": "100"
    },
    {
        "employeeId": 3,
        "name": "Johnny Rahme",
        "dob": "1/10/2001 12:00:00 AM",
        "salary": "100"
    }
]
```

On my app.component.html I have this:

```
<table class='table'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>EmployeeId</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let emp of empList">
    <td>{{ emp.EmployeeId }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.DOB }}</td>
    <td>{{ emp.Salary }}</td>
    <td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

On my app.component.ts I have:

```
this.empList = data // that contains the data from an api
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propery names in tempalte are not same as your objects in your component. Notice the first letter of your property names in your template are all uppercase whereas in your component all letters are lowercase. Change your template with the following please.

```
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let emp of empList">
            <td>{{ emp.employeeId }}</td>
            <td>{{ emp.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ emp.dob}}</td>
            <td>{{ emp.salary }}</td>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l7nkqa)**